# Xaml Storyboard in a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a problem with an animantion of an UserControl.

1. The animation runs only once.
2. If I have multiple instances of my UserControl in another window, the animation is called for every Instance of the UserControl.

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="My_UserControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                mc:Ignorable="d" Margin="10,10">
       <UserControl.Resources>
           <Storyboard x:Key="CartTicket_Whip">
               <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControlGrid">
                   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-2"/>
                   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
               </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControlGrid">
                   <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="True"/>
                   <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="False"/>
               </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           </Storyboard>
       </UserControl.Resources>

       <UserControl.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="DecrementButton">
               <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartTicket_Whip}"/>
           </EventTrigger>
       </UserControl.Triggers>

       <Grid x:Name="UserControlGrid" Height="60">
           <Grid.LayoutTransform>
               <TransformGroup>
                   <ScaleTransform/>
                   <SkewTransform/>
                   <RotateTransform/>
                   <TranslateTransform/>
               </TransformGroup>
           </Grid.LayoutTransform>
           <Grid.Effect>
               <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" Color="Silver"></DropShadowEffect>
           </Grid.Effect>
           <DockPanel Background="White">
               <Button Name="DecrementButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="-" FontSize="40" Width="60">
               </Button>
               <TextBlock x:Name="TicketCount" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="2 x" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10">
                   <TextBlock.Effect>
                       <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Color="Silver"></DropShadowEffect>
                   </TextBlock.Effect>
               </TextBlock>
               <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                   <TextBlock x:Name="TicketName" Text="Ticket type 01" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                       <TextBlock x:Name="PriceTxt" Grid.Column="2" Text="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                       <TextBlock x:Name="PriceTxt_currency" Grid.Column="2" Text=" EUR" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                   </StackPanel>
               </StackPanel>
           </DockPanel>
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `FillBehavior` property of your Storyboard to `Stop` in this way:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CartTicket_Whip" FillBehavior="Stop">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControlGrid">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-2"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControlGrid">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="True"/>
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="False"/>
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks to II Vic the FillBehavior solved the issue with playing the Storyboard only once.. Thanks alot!!! Remains only the 2. problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, I counldn't reproduce your second issue. Can you post your windows xaml please (or at least the most important part of them)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it... sorry it is a dump coincidance! Because I changed the skew of the Grid element, to have a bob up and down effect, the hole usercontrol had this effect.
Now in my window I put five of this UserControls in a Grid, under each other...
So there was the effect, that on every click it seems that evrey UserControl started the animation...

So here the new code, where I make the storyboard for a child element (the dockPanel):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Margin="10,10">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CartTicket_Whip">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControlDockPanel">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-1.5"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="DecrementButton">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartTicket_Whip}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="UserControlGrid" Height="60">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" Color="Silver"></DropShadowEffect>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <DockPanel x:Name="UserControlDockPanel" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <DockPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </DockPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Button Name="DecrementButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="-" FontSize="40" Width="60">
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TicketCount" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="2 x" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Color="Silver"></DropShadowEffect>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TicketName" Text="Ticket type 01" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PriceTxt" Grid.Column="2" Text="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PriceTxt_currency" Grid.Column="2" Text=" EUR" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```